# Proof of $\nabla\times\vec{E}=0\Rightarrow\exists\Phi:\vec{E}=\nabla\Phi$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Would anyone be able to help me prove these two statements involving vector fields?
For a suitable region
$$\nabla\times\vec{E}=0\Rightarrow\exists\Phi:\vec{E}=\nabla\Phi$$
and
$$\nabla\cdot\vec{B}=0\Rightarrow\exists\vec{A}:\vec{B}=\nabla\times\vec{A}$$
Many thanks

Comment: "In a simply-connected region an irrotational vector field has the path independence property. This can be seen by noting that in such a region an irrotational vector field is conservative, and conservative vector fields have the path independence property. The result can also be proved directly by using Stokes' theorem. In a connected region any vector field which has the path independence property must also be irrotational." Start from this sentence from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field

Comment: Well, the first one is quite straightforward. Both of them are simple consequences of the [Poincare lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_lemma#Poincar.C3.A9_lemma) (if the fields are defined on an appropriate domain). Maybe someone knows a straightforward way to prove the second equality without using such strong tools, but I don't, at least not right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existence of the potentials depend on the shape of your region. More explicitly, they depend on the first and second [de Rham cohomology groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology) of the region vanishing. This is not always the case. It is true for convex sets, and more generally $p$-convex sets, defined below. However, proving it for more general spaces requires more advanced machinery, like homotopy invariance et cetera.

If your region $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is $p$-convex for a certain point $p\in U$, meaning that it contains the line segment connecting $p$ to any other point in $U$, then the scalar and vector potentials can be explicitly constructed as follows:

Let $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ be a $C^2$ vector field on a $p$-convex region $U$, where we choose $p$ to be the origin (We can always translate the coordinates to make it so).

1) If $\text{curl}(f)=0$, then there exists a function $F:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i} = f_i$ for $i=1,2,3$, given by
$$F(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \int_0^1 x_1 f(t x)+x_2f_2(tx) + x_3 f_3(tx) \text{d}t$$ where $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

2) If $\text{div}(f)=0$, then there exists a $F:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\text{curl}(F)=f$, given by
$$F(x) = \int_0^1 f(tx)\times (tx) \text{d}t$$

I'll let you check that these $F$'s really do give the desired results. The calculations are not very difficult.

Comment: Without loss of generality we may assume that $p=\mathbf{0}$ as you did.

Comment: Indeed, the formulas I gave for $F$ are only valid when $p=0$.

Comment: Thank you this is fantastic!! Just one question:
is $F_{x_1}=\int_0^1 f_1(tx) + \sum_{i=1}^3 x_it \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial tx_1} dt$ and if so how does this equal $f_1$?
for 1.

Comment: You expression is not quite right. We get $F_{x_1}=\int_0^1 f_1(tx)+\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i t \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i}(tx)dt$. If you now calculate $\frac{d}{dt} tf_1(tx)$, plug this into your integral and use the assumption $\text{curl}(f)=0$, you should get what you want. This problem is not a straight path. You have to take some detours and "see" what quantities you want to have in your integral.